# RxJS: debounceTime on Rx.Observable.interval is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, debouncing

In the following line of code I am expecting the printing of `here` every 2 seconds. But nothing is being printed:

`Rx.Observable.interval(1000).debounceTime(2000).subscribe(x => console.log('here'))`

However in the following line of code, `here` is printed every 2 seconds, as expected:

`Rx.Observable.interval(2000).debounceTime(1000).subscribe(x => console.log('here'))`

In the first case I am expecting an event stream of 1 second period to be debounced to 2 seconds period. This does not seem to work.

And in the second case I am expecting an event stream of 2 seconds period to be debounced to 1 second period. This seems to work.

Why is the first case not working as expected? Is there something wrong in my expectation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may confuse **debounce** with **throttle**.

### debounceTime

For every item, wait X ms until no other item is emitted, and **only then** emits the item.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).debounceTime(2000).subscribe(x => console.log('here'))
```

All items are dropped since an item will always be emitted within 2000 ms.

### throttleTime

Emits an item if no other items were emitted during the last X ms. Otherwise, the item is dropped.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).throttleTime(2000).subscribe(x => console.log('here'))
```

Prints an item every 2000 ms.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I did misunderstand debounceTime.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first case is that you are creating a new interval every second, but telling the observable to wait until 2 seconds have passed in order to pass the object through to the subscription. Since the `interval` value is less than the `debounceTime` value, your subscription will never "resolve".